# How do I swap a pre defined array element using an index?

Tags: c++, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

I'm trying to swap two array elements that are initialized strings (see code below), I thought i knew how to do it but the way I tried doesn't seem to be working. We're not allowed to use the function "swap" that I've seen on many other forum sights with a similar question as mine. Therefore I've used a temporary index variable to swap them but that doesn't seem to be working. Not sure how to fix it and make it work, so my question is how do I do it.

I'm pretty new to programming so the answer may not be as evident to me yet. I've been staring at this for a while and still can't see it, I also tried asking on reddit but they didn't give me a very concise or helpful answer. If you could help me out as to why it wont swap the elements that would be great and if you see any other bugs or improvements I could make please let me know, your feedback is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(string names[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << names[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 0, a, b;
    string answer, name1, name2;
    string index;
    string names[7] = {"John", "Dave", "Jim", "Amanda", "Kelsey", "Don",   "Jennifer"};
    printArray(names);

    while (x < 1) {
        cout << endl << "Do you want to swap students? " << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == "Yes" || answer == "yes") {
            cout << "Who would you like to swap?" << endl;
            cin >> name1;

            for(a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
                if (names[a] == name1) {
                    cout << "Yes, " << name1 << " is in the line." << endl;
                }

            }

            cout << "Who would you like to swap " << name1 << " for?" << endl;
            cin >> name2;

            for(b = 0; b < 7; b++) {
                if (names[b] == name2) {
                    cout << "Yes, " << name2 << " is in the line!!" << endl;

                    index = names[a];
                    names[a] = names[b];
                    names[b] = index;

                    printArray(names);
                }

            }



        } else {
            cout << endl << "Thanks, please behave now, students!" << endl;
            x++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

More context:

Print out the current class line-up (i.e., the current contents of the array, in order).
Present the user with a prompt asking if they would like to swap 2 students. 
If they say yes, proceed to step 3.
Ask the user for the names of the two students to be swapped.
If the two students are both in the array, swap their positions in the array.  If either student is not in the class, print an error message on the console, e.g. "Sorry, you have to pick 2 students who are in the line!".
No matter the outcome of step 4, return to step 1.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While searching for `name1` ,the loop runs till 7 no matter if its found or not which messes with your swapping task:

```
index = names[a];  //a=7
names[a] = names[b];  //a=7
names[b] = index;.
```

Use `break`:

```
if (names[a] == name1) {

        cout << "Yes, " << name1 << " is in the line." << endl;
        break;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I've been hitting my head against my screen for the entire day, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The value of a is always 7 while swapping is being done! So it is not working.